# Proof that a degree $4$ polynomial has a minimum

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $$f(x) = x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0.$$ Prove that $f(x)$ has a minimum point in $\Bbb{R}$.

The Extreme Value Theorem implies that the minimum exists in some $[a,b]$, but how do I find the right $a$ and $b$?

Comment: How does behave the function when $x$ takes infinite positive and negative values ?

Comment: I think the point is that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty$.  So there must be a minimum somewhere in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = +\infty$, for any $M \in \Bbb R$ one can find $b \in \Bbb R$ such that $x > b$ implies $f(x) > M$. Similarly, $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = +\infty$...

Comment: You also need to consider the limit to $-\infty$ no?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, but the argument is symmetric (I've added a comment to this effect anyway).

Comment: And then what? I need to choose an $M$ whose $f(y)=M$ is close enough to the minimum point. I think I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: @iTayb $M$ doesn't need to be particularly close to the minimum value, in fact, it's certainly enough to choose it be any value that $f$ achieves (certainly taking $M := f(0) = a_0$ would do). The argument gives an interval $[a, b]$ outside of which the value of $f$ is always larger than $M$, and hence $f$ achieves a minimum inside that interval.

Comment: @Travis Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $x>|a_3|+\sqrt{|a_2|}+\sqrt[3]{|a_1|}+\sqrt[4]{|a_0|}$ then $f(x)>0$.